# "An" used in place of "And"?

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation

**I'm baking a meatloaf an homemade mac an cheese for din din!!!!yummie!!!**

Explain the improper use of "an" in the above sentence.

Shouldn't it be written as? :
"I'm baking a meatloaf and making Mac and Cheese for Din-Din."

Comment: I've closevoted as Primarily Opinion-Based (how can *we* explain better than *you* why you chose the non-standard orthography?). But it could just as well be General Reference that even people who actually do know how to spell simple words like ***and*** might sometimes choose non-standard spellings that reflect *how they actually **pronounce** the words*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or how we all pronounce them!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a deliberate use of a different spelling to show how the speaker pronounces the words, if it is not an outright typographical mistake.